# One Controller with many views for table per type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, table-per-type

I have a table per type structure, I want to write an mvc razor application where my only parameter in the mvc routing is the primary key ID. From there the application will establish which type in my tpt structure the ID belongs to then displays the view formatted for particular type.

In addition, based on the type of the ID the view will also contain information related to that ID in from other tables in the tpt structure.

E.g.
Bob is a person with ID 1234

- Entity 1234 has comments in the comments table
- Entity 1234 has an entry in the entity relationship table to Simon

I've read a number of articles about making a base class controller, but would my URL change from `www.something.burp/1234?`

Is it possible to have a set of Index, Edit, Create, Details views that have byType separation?

Just looking for some pointers or ideas for me to research.

Thanks for you help.

---

MVC4, EF4, C#, SQL 2008

Answer (score 0):

Decided to do multi controller, it's not going to matter to the user if it goes between controllers.